# How to make Worksheet_SelectionChange under the whole workbook range?

Tags: excel, vba

I want to use VBA to get the the active cell's value. By searching online, I found below codes.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
Sheets("sheet1").Range("Selection").Value = Cells(ActiveCell.Row, ActiveCell.Column).Value
End Sub
```

However, I have to put these codes under sheet "sheet1". If I have three sheets, `sheet1, sheet2, and sheet3`, I need to copy the above codes, and paste under those three sheets separately, with a little modification.

Is there some way that I don't need to put the codes in separate sheets(just under ThisWorkbook maybe), while I can still get the activecell's value no matter which sheet is activated.

Thanks

Comment: you could use the `Workbook_SheetSelectionChange` event in ThisWorkbook.

Comment: @ScottCraner if I use Workbook_SheetSelectionChange and put it under ThisWorkbook, I got Compile error: Procedure declaration does not match description of event or procedure having the same name.

Comment: The `SheetSelectionChange` event handler signature includes an `Object` parameter representing the sheet that raised the event.

Comment: @Mat'sMug Is there some way to bypass this problem(using another function)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you want is what [@ScottCraner said in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36093518/how-to-make-worksheet-selectionchange-under-the-whole-workbook-range/36093746#comment59831337_36093518): use the `SheetSelectionChange` event of the `Workbook` type, in `ThisWorkbook`.

The VBE provides dropdowns in the code pane editor, specifically for this. You can't just copy/paste event handlers from a `Worksheet` object into a `Workbook` object and expect things to "just work" - use the dropdowns and have the VBE generate the handler stubs for you!

[image: use the dropdowns!]

Selecting `SheetSelectionChange` from the dropdown will generate this handler:

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetSelectionChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)

End Sub
```

As you can see the signatures are different:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

End Sub
```

Event handlers must adhere to the *signature* (not just the name) of the event they're for, otherwise you get the error you're getting:

> *@ScottCraner if I use Workbook_SheetSelectionChange and put it under ThisWorkbook, I got Compile error: **Procedure declaration does not match description of event or procedure having the same name.***

Comment: Thanks for the explanation with the pic. Now it works.